# Errno 10049:creating UDP socket

Tags: python, udp

The code is for creating client UDP socket. I dont know what's wrong.

```
# UDPPingerClient.py

from socket import *

serverName = '';
serverPort = 12000;


clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

message = raw_input("Input message:")
clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName,serverPort))

modifiedMessage, serverAddress = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
print(modifiedMessage)
print(serverAddress)
clientSocket.close()
```

> Errno 10049 in line 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you are using Windows based on the error number, which according to [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740668(v=vs.85).aspx), Errno 10049 is the following:

> Cannot assign requested address.
>   The requested address is not valid in its context. This normally results from an attempt to bind to an address that is not valid for the local computer. This can also result from connect, sendto, WSAConnect, WSAJoinLeaf, or WSASendTo when the remote address or port is not valid for a remote computer (for example, address or port 0).

Which is possibly caused by attempting to send and receive using the same socket. So you will want to create two sockets, one for receiving and one to send the information.

Comment: No, this is because he using empty address

Answer (score 0):

MSDN:

> WSAEADDRNOTAVAIL 10049
>   Cannot assign requested address.
>
> The requested address is not valid in its context. This normally results from an attempt to bind to an address that is not valid for
>   the local computer. This can also result from `connect`, `sendto`,
>   `WSAConnect`, `WSAJoinLeaf`, or `WSASendTo` when the remote address or port
>   is not valid for a remote computer (for example, address or port 0).

This is because you attempting to call `sendto` with empty `serverName`. Use valid address like `'example.com'`, `'127.0.0.1'`, `'0.0.0.0'` and it will works.

When you call `sendto` on new socket it firstly try to convert server address and port to presentation, which usable by system API. Empty string is not a valid address and you get error.